# Let $A$ be an infinitely countable set and let $B$ be a finite set. Show that $A \cup B$ is also countable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $A$ be an infinitely countable set an let $B$ be a finite set. Show that $A \cup B$ is also countable.

In the solution for this exercise, a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to A \cup \left ( B \setminus A\right )$ is constructed as follows: $$ f(n) = \begin{cases}b_n \text{ if } 1 \leq n \leq N_0\\ g(n - N_0)  \text{ if } n \geq N_0 +1 \end{cases}$$ From here we show that this function is bijective.

Where $|B \setminus A| = N_0$

I am confused on how this function is constructed. I understand the upper portion of the piecewise function, but not really the lower portion. That is, how/why is $g(n - N_0)$ there?

A detailed explanation would be grand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the missing part is that $g: \Bbb N\to A$ is the inverse of the bijective function $\tilde{f}:A\to \Bbb N$ guaranteed by the infinite countability of $A$. Thus, $g(n-N_0)$ takes the consecutive values $g(1),\,g(2),$ etc., which counts every element of $A$ precisely once by assumption. In particular, the function $f(n)$ is a bijective function from $\Bbb N$ to $A\cup B$.